# No rule to make target '/lib/libjawt.dylib', needed by 'fingerqualityscore'. Stop

Tags: linux, cmake

Trying to generate a .so file from a C++ project for linux.

I am working on creating jni methods that can called wihin a java project

I keep this error once I try to build. *** No rule to make target '/lib/libjawt.dylib', needed by 'name'.

```cmake
#minimum version of CMake for this project
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION "3.17")

# name of this example project
project(name VERSION 1.0.0)

set(JAWT_LIBRARY "/path/to/libjawt.dylib")
set(OpenCV_DIR /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include")
set(JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include")
set(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin")
set(JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/lib/libjawt.dylib")
set(JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/lib/server/libjvm.dylib")

find_package(Java REQUIRED)
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include(UseJava)

#message(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include)
include_directories(/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include/linux)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include_directories(main)
include_directories(include)

file (GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES src/*.h src/*.cpp)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
add_executable(name ${SOURCES})

#Set all necessary libraries 
set(LIBS ${JNI_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}) 

target_link_libraries(name ${LIBS})

#Native build

#Generate the shared library from the sources
add_library(native-name SHARED ${SOURCES})
install(TARGETS native-name DESTINATION /usr/lib)
target_link_libraries(native-name ${LIBS})
```

This is a snippet of my cmakelist file

Comment: `$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/lib/libjawt.dylib` results in `/lib/libjawt.dylib` - isn't the issue obvious?

Comment: Dynamic libraries on Linux usually have `.so` as their suffix. The `.dyllib` one is MacOS.